Why NVDA does not read output's label?
I wanted to use <output> element, because I thought it's the best solution in terms of accesibility (and maybe SEO) for calculated valeus (I have two <input>s and one <output>). NVDA reads all changed outputs first, and then all labels.
I also use JS, somthing like this:
input1.addEventListener("input", ev => {
   let calculations = ev.target.value * smth;
   // ...
   installment.textContent = calculations + " EUR";
}

I tried some of this solutions but it doesn't work on Windows + Edge + NVDA:
<label for="installment">Installment: </label>
<output id="installment"></output>

and
<label id="installment_label">Installment: </label>
<output id="installment" aria-labelledby="installment_label"></output>

I also tried to add role="status" but it didn't work as well.

While this solution works good (although NVDA reads something like "10 000 EUR, Installment" it's still better):
Edit:
<label id="installment_label" aria-live="assertive">Installment:
    <span id="installment" aria-labelledby="installment_label"></span>
</label>

What would by the best solution? Should I stay with <label id=x><span aria-labelledby=x>?

What is input1 a <form> element ? it seems to me 'input'  is a form event...

The label element with the for attribute is used to give form controls an accessible name. The output element is not a form control, so this would explain why using a label with an output is not working the way you expect it to. Also, your aria-labelledby solution probably won't work for all screen readers because you can't technically give a span an accessible name. It might help if you describe more what you are trying to do here and then we could offer a solution.

Although <output> can hold text like a content type element you should use .value instead of .textContent. When you assign .value it isn't actual content like text nodes, it's an attribute/property value, so that might change how a screen reader interprets <output> and it's associated <label>.

Your third example is probably wrong, as you can't say that the label of something is that thing itself or a part of it.

@MisterJojo input1 is <input type="range" element, I used input event because change only works when you stop holding slider's "thumb"

You should try something like this, using aria-atomic:
<label for="installment">Installment:</label>
<output id="installment" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></output>


When set to aria-atomic="true", the entire changed region as a whole will be presented, including the updated node's label, if there is one.

